# What is the solid Windows Server 2008 VPS hosting (preferably) in Europe?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hosting, vps

I am looking for Windows Server 2008 VPS hosting to host a few sites/apps with special needs.

I spend few hours googling but I am not satisfied with the result. I looks to me that this business is full of crap. Two thirds of the reviews seems to be faked and advertised offers is  unavailable or contains some hidden fee.

So my question is which VPS hosting with Windows Server 2008 do you recommend? I slightly prefer data center in Europe and euro payment it isn't deal breaker.

---

*Note*: I didn't made question community wiki because I am interested in answers from users with some reputation and I want to preserve theirs answers.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Rackspace only offers cloud server in US. And their Windows Server cloud servers are still in beta.

I recommend PoundHost or Ultima Hosts. I have VPS with both companies and have no complaints, but I have better experience with PoundHost's support.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Bytemark](http://www.bytemark.co.uk/) or [Memset](http://www.memset.com/), both UK-based. I’ve not used Bytemark myself, but people whose opinions I trust have. I have a couple of (Linux) VPSes at Memset, but they do Windows too and are very solid.

Answer (score 0):

Rackspace is a pretty good host (I've used them in the US) and they offer a cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EC2 has a datacenter in Ireland.  A reserved small instance running Windows Server 2008, up 24x7 over 3 years, averages out to something like US$60 per month including MS licensing. Looking at the pricing of some of the other reputable Euro hosts that have been suggested, I get the impression that this is very competitive for a Windows server with 1.7 gigs of RAM.

Of course, with EC2, you pay as you go for bandwidth and persistent storage, and the learning curve for Amazon's cloud model is significant compared to just signing on with a vanilla hosting provider.  On the other hand, you know exactly what you're getting, you can be sure that you're buying it from a solid company that has world-class uptime/connectivity, and you know that your provider won't disappear tomorrow.  Also, you can "try before you buy" for pennies an hour with an on-demand instance.

I am not personally familiar with any of the reputable, euro-based hosting companies suggested by others in this thread, but it's quite possible that one of them would be a better fit for your needs.  I just wanted to make sure that you were aware of Amazon EC2 as one possible solution.  Be sure to consider all of your options before you leap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently hosting my system on a dedicated server at http://www.server4you.net/ (actually at their polish branch http://serwerydlaciebie.pl)

I'm happy with their service - even when due to my error I made our server inaccessible from the network and they arranged a VPN connection to a recovery console.

They are cheap and have a great 100Gbit/s network connection (our cheapest dedicated server speed is limited by a switch on their local network to 100Mbit/s).

You pay for each month upfront and can resign without a cancellation period - you just don't pay for the next month.

Comment: Does server4you support Windows Server 2008 hosing? I cannot find such offer.

Comment: They do, but not VPS servers, only on dedicated machines (but still they are quite cheap), the Windows Web Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I am hosting on server4you.net some years now with 2 server and never have serious problems. They are good and have low price. I like them a lot.